# Unable to modify element with JS before AJAX call

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

## The problem:

I was unable to find any resources online regarding changing elements before and after an ajax request. If I have a `<p>` element with `id="myText"`, if I want to change the `innerHTML` of that element before the `AJAX` request, and after, this is not possible.

I essentially want to change the text of `#myText` to "loading..." on click of the button, then run my `AJAX` request, and within that request, on success it changes that elements text from "loading...", to `data`, which works. However, the "loading..." does not show.

When I check devTools, I can see that the innerHTML is indeed changing to "Loading...", but it just does not show. If I remove the `AJAX` request, the element successfully changes to "loading..."

```
$(function() {
    $('#uploadBtn').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'loading...'
        var form_data = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/flaskFunction',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = data
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('#textArea').val('loading...')` use this

Comment: why not just change it on click before the ajax call?

Comment: @Pedram it is a `<p>` element, not a `<textarea>`

Comment: @safnasfsa so: `$('#textArea').text('loading...')`

Answer (score 0):

How about this, just set the value on click and if there is an error show it or just clear the element.

```
$(function() {
    $('#upload-file-btn2').click(function() {
        var form_data = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
        document.getElementById('textArea').innerHTML = 'loading...';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/flaskFunction',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
            },
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById('textArea').innerHTML = data
            },
            error: function(data) {
            
                document.getElementById('textArea').innerHTML = "failed"
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It is displaying the success function correctly. But the innnerHTML of the element before is not working (loading...) @Caleb

Answer (score 0):

If an element with id "textArea" is an actual `textarea` tag then you can't set the content of it with innerHTML. You need to use value, like any form control.

```js
document.getElementById('textArea').value = 'loading...'
```

Comment: It is a `<p>` element, not a `<textarea>` @jcubic

Answer (score 0):

I actually can't get your example to NOT work  Is it possible that the text is actually changing, but the request executes so quickly that you just don't see it on the screen? If you can see the change in devtools, it should be happening. Try this in your `success()` function to wait 2 seconds before changing the text from `'loading...'` to `data`:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = data
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. The problem is, that you trigger the AJAX with 'async: false'. If you do that, the UI-Process from the web browser hangs and will work further, after the AJAX call is done. I see two possibilities:

1. Work without *async: false*
2. Move the AJAX-Part into a function and trigger the code with setTimeout. Example:

   ```
    function theNewFunction() {
    var form_data = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/flaskFunction',
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = data
        }
    });
   ```

   }

Call the function now via:

```
$(function() {
    $('#uploadBtn').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'loading...'
        setTimeout(theNewFunction, 1);
    });
});
```

Timeout of 1 is enough for me.